# Splice an array in React keeps rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lit-element

In the update(changeProps) function, I have something like this:

```js
 update(changedProps) {
      if (this.person) {
        this.__arr = ['hi', 'hi', 'hi'];
      } else {
        this.__arr = ['bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye'];
      }

    if (this.__hello) {
      this.__arr.splice(1, 0, 'hello');
    }

    super.update(changedProps);
  }
```

Say this.person is true, when I click elsewhere and the page rerenders, it becomes

```
this.__arr = ['hi', 'hello', 'hi', 'hi']
```

Then when it rerenders again: `this.__arr = ['hi', 'hello','hello', 'hi', 'hi']`

It keeps adding to the array after each rerender. Same for if this.person is not true. How do I make it so it only adds it once?

If I did something like this: `this.__arr = [...this.__arr, 'hello']`, it can add it to the end, but I want to add an element to index 1

Comment: What is the `update(changeProps)` function? Do you mean `componentDidUpdate`? In general, you should avoid all mutating functions (like `splice`) on `props` or `state`

Comment: @Adam If there is a change to one of my private properties, insert 'hello' into the array.

And good call. I have to insert it into index 1 though, unsure how to do it without splice though.

Comment: Post more code - don't just post the `splice` - post the rest of the function declaration around it - i.e. add more context.

Comment: To insert at index 1 - `this._arr = [...this._arr].splice(1,0,'hello')`

Comment: Sorry. I added more code. The way you mentioned provides be a blank array

Comment: What is `update`? Are you extending something that is not `React.Component` or `React.PureComponent`?

Comment: Its from litelement life cycle. Kind of new to it, but I believe if a private variable changes, it gets rerendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Don't mutate:

```
    if (this.__hello) {
      this.__arr = [...this.__arr].splice(1, 0, 'hello');
    }
```

2. Do you want to do this every time the component updates, or just once?

```
    if (this.__hello && this.__arr[1] !== 'hello') {
      this.__arr = [...this.__arr].splice(1, 0, 'hello');
    }
```

Comment: Oh the this.__arr[1] !== 'hello' did the trick. thanks so much for your help! I wanted to only update once.